Can't figure out how to download image to webpage and display it using JAX-RS
I have be googling for days trying to figure out how to download a PNG image from a java servlet using JAX-RS to a React MUI front end.   The Problem is all the examples are for only one side and they don't talk about how to read/send it from the other side.   This is my test code:
Java 17 servlet using Jersey bookmarks:
    @GET // get data
    @Path("downloadPanoramas") // file/downloadPanoramas is URL
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM) // what format we be use
    public Response getPanoramas4()
    {
        Response result;

        try
        {
            final String fileName = "pano_vis_a_panorama.png";
            java.nio.file.Path panoramaPath = get(YamlReader.getImagePath(), fileName);
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(panoramaPath.toFile());
            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", outputStream);
            byte[] encodedImage = Base64.encode(outputStream.toByteArray());

            Response.ResponseBuilder builder = Response.ok(encodedImage).header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
            // All Done.
            result = builder.build();
        }
        catch (IOException | RuntimeException ex)
        {
            JsonObject resultMsg = Json.createObjectBuilder().add("status",
                            Json.createObjectBuilder().add("code", 1)
                                    .add("message", ex.getMessage())
                                    .build())
                    .build();
            return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(resultMsg.toString()).build();
        }

        return result;
    }

Function is reading in the get request and then sends the image back which I want to display on my web page.  I am see most post say to use responseType "arraybuffer" but no one talks about how to do that on the backend.  I mimic the the request examples to create the js frontend file.
React front end
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import React, {useEffect, useRef, useState} from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import axios from "axios";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import {Buffer} from 'buffer';

const API_ENDPOINT = process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT;
const SERVLET_NAME = process.env.REACT_APP_SERVLET_NAME;

function PanoramaTool(props) {
    const [image64, setImage64] = useState("");

    const url_DP  = API_ENDPOINT + "/" + SERVLET_NAME + "/rdt/file/downloadPanoramas"; // Download panorama file request

    const getImage = () => {
        axios({
            method: 'GET',
            url: url_DP,
            responseType: 'arraybuffer',
        }).then((response) => {
                setImage64(Buffer.from(response.data, "binary").toString("base64"))
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        })
    };

    /**
     Create the step layout.
     */
    // noinspection JSValidateTypes
    return (
        <Box sx={{ margin: 2 }}>
            <Typography variant="h2" align="center" sx={{mb: 1}} gutterBottom>
                Panorama Configuration
            </Typography>
            <Box>
                <Box>
                    <img src={`data:image/png;base64,${image64}`} alt="pano_vis_a_panorama.png"/>
                    <Button onClick={getImage} sx={{ mt: 1, mr: 1 }}>
                        panorama
                    </Button>
                </Box>
            </Box>
        </Box>
    );
}

export default PanoramaTool;

When the response is read in the PanoramaTool it matches the string the backend sent, so it should be base64.   However; the web page only shows the Alt message.  So what I am doing wrong?

I switch to setImage64(response.data.toString('binary')); and the catch error stopped, but no image is being display in the img src block.

I installed npm install --save buffer --legacy-peer-deps and imported Buffer so the convert line now works.  I see a long hex string at the img line, but there is no picture appearing on the web page.

I have updated my example to the current code version.  I have also tried to do text interface, but the string are still the same in the end and no image is displayed.

I used a smaller png to verify the base64 output was valid, if was, and the image appeared on the webpage.   So the problem is the png panorama  image I am trying to display is 65.5 MB (65,545,695 bytes).    I am not sure what to do about this.   Is this a javascript string restriction or image too big to display without reducing it somehow?  Any ideas?
